# Forcing RadToolTip in WPF to stay open even if moved out of control focus

Tags: wpf, telerik

I am using radtooltipservice to display tooltip for control in my wpf application. Currently, we can use showDuration to make the radtooltip visible for long time. My requirement is to keep the radtooltip open even if its parent control has lost focus i.e whenever I am moving away from the control the tooltip is getting hidden. Is there any way to keep it open even if the mouse is not on the tooltip.

**Note : I am using WPF application. The tooltip is for WPF control**
Thanks

Comment: Will be easy to use Popup instead of (Rad)ToolTipService, it has property StaysOpen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used Pop up and it was working fine. I wanted to know if pop up kind of behavior can be achieved using Tooltip